# Custom upload button works on desktop but not mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently use a custom upload button in my site next to a hidden file input with a class of `.invisible-file-input`.

I have the following throughout my site:

Javascript

```
 $('.call-upload').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.invisible-file-input').click();
 });
```

CSS

```
.invisible-file-input {
    position: fixed;
    top: -200vh;
}
```

HTML

```
<input class="invisible-file-input" name="document" type="file">

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block call-upload" type="button">
    Upload Document
</button>
```

When the button is clicked it simply opens the file select window, this works fine on desktop browsers but as soon as you use your mobile device, it simply does nothing on button click.

Comment: Can you add the HTML and CSS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a great way to do this using `label`!

Add the hidden input's id into the label's `for` attribute like so...

```
<label class="file-upload-btn" for="inputId">Button Text</label>
```

Then style `label.file-upload-btn` in css with the styles you are using for the button now. It will look exactly the same, but the file upload dialog will be consistent now due to the label forcing the related input to be focused.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('.call-upload').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.invisible-file-input').get(0).click();
 });
```

Comment: Works on desktop, still does nothing on mobile though

Comment: Can you show me the CSS definition of `.invisible-file-input`?